# Unable to fetch "user information" on my mail id through the "mail()" function

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch "user information" on my mail id through the "mail()" function in php.the **mail()** function worked fine previously but now it's not working.Here is my HTML code:

```
<form name="contactForm" class="standard-form row-fluid" action="contact.php" method="post" >
 <input class="span6" name="themeple_name" placeholder="Name" type="text" id="themeple_name" value="" / style="float:left; background-color:#fff;">

<input class="span6" name="themeple_email" placeholder="E-Mail" type="text" id="themeple_email" value="" / style="background-color:#fff;">

 <input class="span6" name="themeple_subject" placeholder="Subject" type="text" id="themeple_subject" value="" required>

 <textarea class="span12" placeholder="Message" name="themeple_message" cols="40" rows="7" id="themeple_message" style="background-color:#fff;"></textarea>

 <p class="perspective">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" class="btn-system normal default" /> </p>
</form>
```

This is my php file:

```
<?php 

    $headers = "From: xyz@gmail.com";
    $to = "xyz@gmail.com"; 
    $Email = $_POST['themeple_email'];
    $Name = $_POST['themeple_name'];
    $Subject = $_POST['themeple_subject'];
    $Message = $_POST['themeple_message'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $email_message = "Form details below. \r\n";
    $email_message .= "Name: ".$Name. "\r\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".$Email. "\r\n";
    $email_message .= "subject: ".$Subject. "\r\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".$Message. "\r\n";

    mail ($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);
    header("Location: thank-you.html");



//echo "MAIL SENT " . $Name . $Email . $Phone . $Message;
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please define: "is not working". Do you get any errors? Is the mail delivered?

Comment: why there is a / after value=""?

Comment: u get any errors?

Comment: where is the condition your send email page.

please check first condition and try to run it is work or not.

Comment: no, i didn't get any errors, when I submitted the form it redirects to thank you page successfully, but mail is not delivered to me.

Comment: are you running this in your local machine?

Comment: first check `print_r($_POST).` data is get or not in print_r, check it

Comment: @ caryarit ferrer "/" is closing the input tags. and i,m running this on web server.

Comment: @Shubham running this in local server ?

Comment: First try to check condition like: 
 If(mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers)){
echo "Email Sent";
}

Comment: @Moorthy but how to configure the mail function in local server...???

Comment: you can't close the tag and put more attributes afterwards

Comment: @caryarit ferrer ok, thanks for the corrections, I had fixed it but still it,s not working.

Comment: try activating all error and coment the redirection, if there is a mistake it will give you a clue

Comment: If you are trying to sent mail from local workstation using WAMP, MAMP, or XAMPP.. you need to configure mail  server or you can use PHPMailer class

Comment: some points need to clear here, 1) are you working on your local machine? localhost? 2) have you dunp post data on your php file like echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); ? 3)  if all is good, then, comment your header redirection in php file and check mail error like this => $success = mail('example@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
if (!$success) {
    $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
}